# Turn off Eclipse formatter everywhere

Tags: eclipse

I'm looking to disable the eclipse formatter everywhere not in a small section.  Is there perhaps a plugin file that can be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you can actually disable that one command ("Format", part of the "Java" command groups).
But you can at least:

- remove the key binding (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)to that command, through the "Keys" preferences.
- make sure the properties of the project don't define a "format on save" action.

Comment: Yeah, looks as though it's impossible to disable outright.  I had done the saving thing already but due to my tendencies to type 'crtl+shift+f' for find i would accidentally auto format.  Had to rebind it to 'find'

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to find a way of fixing my impulse action :) !

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for the command, you can disable the auto-formatting during a save through the preferences.

Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions, and then unselect "Format source code".

Answer (score 0):

See the description for the formatter on/off tags (assuming this was asked about Java) here: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/whatsNew/jdt_whatsnew.html#JavaFormatter